# Can I revive a friend, once he becomes a ghost?

Tags: spelunky-hd

I'm playing Spelunky on Xbox with my girlfriend. When one of us dies, he/she changes to a ghost.

Is there a way to change this ghost back to life? We tried carrying the dead body to the exit door, but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know of at least one way: if you can find a coffin -- the kind that normally holds unlockable characters in a single-player game -- it will bring a dead player back to life. If multiple players are dead, the one that has been dead the longest will be brought back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every level that is started with a player dead has a coffin in it somewhere, meaning that if a player died on one level, a coffin is going to be on every level until they're revived. Only one person is revived at each coffin, and I believe it is random.
    If an unlockable character, such as Meat Boy or Van Helsing, appears on your level, (bad examples as their spawns are not random, but they are more recognizable character names than, say, Lime) appears on a level where a character dies, striking that character's coffin will instead revive your teammate, instead of giving you the character.